# How do I reliably export cc_type and cc_last4 with auth.net Direct Post?

Tags: payment, export, ee-1.13, authorize.net

I am using the Authorize Direct Post Payment Method with EE 1.13. I need to export credit card payment details including cc_type and cc_last4.  In sales_flat_order_payment cc_type is null and cc_last4 appears to be encrypted.

A few orders include `cc_type` and the unencrypted `cc_last4` in the additional_information field which looks like this:

`a:1:{s:15:"authorize_cards";a:1:{s:32:"61cb8d50438f041ab581a381cd81f8e8";a:13:{s:2:"id";s:32:"61cb8d50438f041ab581a381cd81f8e8";s:16:"requested_amount";s:0:"";s:15:"balance_on_card";s:0:"";s:13:"last_trans_id";s:10:"2195591072";s:16:"processed_amount";s:5:"18.95";s:7:"cc_type";s:2:"VI";s:8:"cc_owner";N;s:8:"cc_last4";s:4:"1111";s:12:"cc_exp_month";s:1:"1";s:11:"cc_exp_year";s:4:"2015";s:11:"cc_ss_issue";N;s:17:"cc_ss_start_month";N;s:16:"cc_ss_start_year";N;}}}`

But most payments additional_information field just looks like

```
a:1:{s:12:"payment_type";s:9:"authorize";}
```

Why do some payments include cc_type and cc_last4 in additional_information and some do not?

How do I reliably capture cc_type and cc_last4 **prior to payment capture** with auth.net Direct Post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to Mage_Authorizenet_Model_Directpost _fillPaymentByResponse()

`->setCcType($response->getXCardType());`

so that

`$payment->setCcAvsStatus($response->getXAvsCode())
                ->setCcLast4($payment->encrypt(substr($response->getXAccountNumber(), -4)));`

becomes

`$payment->setCcAvsStatus($response->getXAvsCode())
                ->setCcLast4($payment->encrypt(substr($response->getXAccountNumber(), -4)))
                ->setCcType($response->getXCardType());`

You'll want to do this in a copy of DirectPost.php in app/code/local/Mage/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php

Answer (score 3):

The field is serialized within additional_data with an `md5(microtime(1))` as the key.

The short answer here is going to be loading the model, <s>unserializing</s>, and exporting to CSV:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);
$payment = $order->getPayment();
```

Once you have the payment object you can coax the `cc_last4` and the `cc_type` out of it (it's an array):

```
$addlinfo = $payment->getAdditionalInformation();
$addlinfo = array_shift($addlinfo['authorize_cards'])); // get only the relevant values from the array
$filepath = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export' . DS . 'cclast4export.csv';

$csvWriter = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csvWriter->saveData($filepath,$addlinfo);
```

In my tests you shouldn't have to decrypt. However, if you do, just use `$payment->decrypt($field)` where $field contains the encrypted information.

The above sample code will write a CSV in `var/export/cclast4export.csv` with ALL of the options. I'll leave it to you (as homework) to pare this down to just the two fields you're requesting.

Hope that helps!

Comment: cc_type is null for all payments and most payments do not have authrorize_cards in additional_information, so  I don't think this solution is going to work. The issue  here is making sure that this data is stored.

Comment: So part of me hopes I'm wrong, but this line https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php#L73  makes me think that you've only authorized those orders and have not captured. In that case you would want to capture the payment...

Comment: That is correct, that I have only authed these payments. I will be capturing them once I receive notification that they have shipped.

Comment: Check back at that time. Authed payments won't have any additional information in the payments table until the funds have been captured.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I need to export cc_type before the capture has occurred.

Comment: That is beyond the bounds of this answer and should be provided in a separate answer. As you mentioned, this isn't captured natively by Magento during authorization.

Comment: @HowieRoss Any movement on this? Anything I can do to help clarify an answer for you?

Comment: I'm looking at class Mage_Authorizenet_Model_Directpost _fillPaymentByResponse(). I'd like to add something like ->setCcType($response->getXCcType()) to it, but that still seems to result in a null cc_type in sales_flat_order_payment. Any suggestions?